# How to adapt the font size to the resolution of my image?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following question.
I am trying to put a watermark on my images with date and time, I have managed to place the data in the image, but my question is: how can I make the size of the text or font that is painted in the image adapt? to the resolution of the image, since in some images it looks good with the size I gave it, which is 20, but in higher resolution images it looks very small: I leave my code here, thanks in advance.

```
QObject::connect(ui->pushButton_3, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [&](){


    QString fileName{"D:/images/IMG_20201231_004236.jpg"};
    QFileInfo fInfo{fileName};
    auto dateTime = fInfo.metadataChangeTime().toString("dd/MM/yyyy h:m");

    QImage newImage{fileName};


    if(newImage.isNull()){
      qInfo() << "Error!!";
      return;
    }
    QPainter painter{&newImage};
    painter.setOpacity(0.5);
    painter.setPen(Qt::white);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 20));
    painter.drawText(newImage.rect(), Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight, dateTime);
    painter.end();
    newImage.save("D:/newImage.jpg");
    qInfo() << "saved image!!!" << '\n';


  });
```

I have not tried a solution yet, since I do not have much experience in Qt and c++, so I come to this forum, thanks

Comment: Figure out what size font looks good on 3 differently sized images, ideally something like 50%, 100%, 150%. Once you know that you should be able to come up with a formula to scale the font size based on the image size versus 100%..

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
int pointSize = (20 * newImage.height()) / D;
painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", pointSize));
```

Where `D` is the height of some reference image that looks good when the font is rendered with a point size of 20.

Comment: hello, i did the following, auto fontSize = (12* newImage.height())/700;
and at least it adjusts something to the images, now what I have a doubt is, when I apply my function to put a watermark on each image of a folder, for example, it closes, when I finish the job, I leave my code here.

Comment: @LincolnIngaroca - I do not understand what you are asking. Can you try asking your question again?

Comment: Sorry, for the comment, it was a mistake to post said comment, I apologize again